# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: NoneType

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried using the same few days back and worked fine. Today I checked and showing AttributeError: Nonetype. Could anyone please help where the error is?

*I removed useragent here

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": 'UserAgent'}

URL = 'https://www.centrepointstores.com/sa/en/Women/Fashion-Accessories/Watches/CENTREPOINT-Citizen-Women%27s-Rose-Gold-Analog-Metal-Strap-Watch-EU-6039-86A/p/EU603986AGold'

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="product-details-name").text
    price = soup.find(id="products-details-price-current-01").text

    print (title)
    print (price)
```

Comment: Have you considered that the website might have changed?

Comment: I did have a look though it didn't seem any different to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `print(soup.text)`, Its show me `Access denied | www.centrepointstores.com used Cloudflare to restrict access` that may cause of `AttributeError: NoneType` error.

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove your `headers`, otherwise the page thinks that your a bot and will block you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.centrepointstores.com/sa/en/Women/Fashion-Accessories/Watches/CENTREPOINT-Citizen-Women%27s-Rose-Gold-Analog-Metal-Strap-Watch-EU-6039-86A/p/EU603986AGold"

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="product-details-name").text
price = soup.find(id="products-details-price-current-01").text

print(title)
print(price)
```

Output:

```
Citizen Women's Rose Gold Analog Metal Strap Watch EU 6039 86A
SAR 339
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows None after I've used different headers. I'll have to get around cloudfare. Thank you for your input